# Using Linq to do: Compile a list of all lists within a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure that Title is clear as mud so let me throw out an example and see if someone can point me in the right direction:

```
public class topObj
{
    public List<midObj> Mids { get; set; }
    public List<botObj> Bots { get { // do some LINQ magic here } }
}
public class midObj
{
    public List<botObj> Bots { get; set; }
}
public class botObj
{
}
```

So, from the top object I'm trying to get a list of all bottom objects that are in a List<> of any of the middle objects that are in the List<> from the top object.

Right now I have something like this:

```
public List<botObj> Bots
    {
        get
        {
            List<botObj> lst = new List<botObj>();
            foreach (midObj mo in Mids)
            {
                lst.AddRange(mo.Bots);
            }

            return lst;
        }
    }
```

It works, of course, but I have to assume there's a way for LINQ to do this in fewer lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 get { return Mids.SelectMany(mid => mid.Bots).ToList(); }
```

I'd also at least consider just returning `IEnumerable<botObj>` rather than a `List`, so that you only spend the effort evaluating it all and putting it in a list if you really need to.  If you know what you're doing by using a list though, feel free to ignore this comment.

Comment: I know IENumerable is much better than List when applied to Entity Framework but is there much of a difference outside EF?  I'm building this in a place where multiple other developers will use it so I typically just use List to make it easier and the only reasons I've heard of using IENumerable were EH-Based ... which we don't use.

Comment: EF doesn't use IEnumerable at all, it uses IQueryable, and while the methods that the two have are almost identical, the actual workings of the two are vastly different.  IEnumerables are still quite useful when dealing with in memory objects (which is all that they are used with).  The idea being that you have a query of an in-memory collection.  You can, at some later point, enumerate the results of that query but the query isn't executed until that point.  In the event that you actually need a List you can always call `ToList` on the results so you don't lose anything returning IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to do something like this:

```
get{ Mids.SelectMany(x => x.Bots).ToList(); }
```

Hope it helps!